# Swift closure in protocol extension

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I want to Decorate UIViewController with the ability to adjust it's interface when `setInteractionEnabled` method is called from another class (ex. Network State Manager). All changes (if any) should be provided in the concrete controller by overriding `onInteractionChanged`. Here is my code:

```
import Foundation

typealias InteractionClosure = ((enabled: Bool) -> Void)

protocol Interaction: class {

    var onInteractionChanged: InteractionClosure? { get set }

    func setInteractionEnabled(enabled: Bool)

}

extension Interaction where Self: UIViewController {

    // Default: Do nothing
    // Throws: - Extensions may not contain stored properties
    var onInteractionChanged: InteractionClosure? = nil

    func setInteractionEnabled(enabled: Bool) {
        onInteractionChanged?(enabled: enabled)
    }

}

extension UIViewController : Interaction {}
```

How to add default implementation for `onInteractionChanged`?

Comment: The error says it all – extensions cannot contain stored properties. You'd have to make it a calculated property that just returns `nil` when accessed. Although does the protocol need to enforce the set-ability of the property `{ get set }`? You'd have to have an empty setter for the default property implementation otherwise. I would make the property a `{ get }` and give conforming types the choice of whether they simply want to override it with a calculated property (get only), or use a stored property (gettable and settable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question is something usually I don't do, but here is my solution:

```
typealias InteractionClosure = (enabled: Bool) -> Void

protocol Interaction: class {

    func addOnInteractionChanged(closure: InteractionClosure)
    func setInteractionEnabled(enabled: Bool)

}

extension Interaction where Self: UIViewController {

    func addOnInteractionChanged(closure: InteractionClosure) {
        onInteractionChanged = closure
    }

    func setInteractionEnabled(enabled: Bool) {
        onInteractionChanged?(enabled: enabled)
    }

    // MARK: - Private

    private var onInteractionChanged: InteractionClosure? {
        get {
            let wrapper =
                objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &icAssociationKey) as? ClosureWrapper
            return wrapper?.closure
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                                     &icAssociationKey,
                                     ClosureWrapper(newValue),
                                     .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }

}

extension UIViewController : Interaction {}

// Helpers

private var icAssociationKey: UInt8 = 0

private class ClosureWrapper {
    var closure: InteractionClosure?

    init(_ closure: InteractionClosure?) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
}
```

Client class:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setup()
    }

    // MARK: - Private

    private func setup() {
        // ...

        addOnInteractionChanged { [unowned self] (enabled) in            
            self.signInButton.enabled = enabled
            self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = !enabled
        }
    }

}
```

In manager class:

```
visibleViewController?.setInteractionEnabled(true)
```

Comment: Solution is work like a charm. But i am confuse at `icAssociationKey`. Why there is need of `icAssociationKey`. What if i remove it ??

Answer (score 3):

If you would like property to have only `{ get }` ability, you can use:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    var testClosure: ((_ parameter: Bool) -> Void)? { get }
}

extension TestProtocol {
    var testClosure: ((_ parameter: Bool) -> Void)? {
        return { parameter in
            print(parameter)
        }
    }
}
```